# Pseudo element isn't working properly. Am I doing wrong? Article:first-child

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make the first paragraph red but all the elements are being red.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiywl.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ex1.css" />
    <style>
      article:first-child {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <h1>heading</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ratione
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate,</p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium
      </p>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am expecting that only first element should be red but everything is being red

Comment: You should take a look at the MDN web docs website for these kind of problems, it is very usefull and gives you examples to better understand how css property works (and even more). In your case, take a look here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Answer (score 3):

You're targetting `article`. To target the first `<p>`, you have to instead do:

```
article p:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
article p:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ratione</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate,</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium</p>
</article>
```

Additionally, `:first-child` selects the first element in a group of sibling elements. For your usecase, `:first-of-type` would work better.